# Cumulative totals for every 3 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employees table which has the following columns and sample data:

```
emp_id|name|salary|cumulative_sal
100     abc  1000   1000
101    gfh   2000   3000
102    jkl   3000   6000
103    ghi   5000   11000
104    tuv   7000   18000
105    mno   2000   20000
```

Now, Iwant to update my cumulative salary in such a way that it is calculated for every 3 rows separately.
Sample

```
emp_id|name|salary|cumulative_sal
100     abc  1000   1000
101    gfh   2000   3000
102    jkl   3000   6000
103    ghi   5000   5000
104    tuv   7000   12000
105    mno   2000   14000
```

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classify 3 rows into a group with `row_number` and then use a cumulative sum per the groups classified. Look at the results of inner query to see how groups are generated.

```
select emp_id,name,salary,sum(salary) over(partition by grp order by emp_id) as cumsum_sal
from (select emp_id,name,salary,(row_number() over(order by emp_id)-1)/3 as grp
      from tbl
     ) t
```

Edit: Based on OP's comment to `update` the table. This can be done with a cte.

```
with cte as 
(select emp_id,name,salary,cumulative_salary,
 sum(salary) over(partition by grp order by emp_id) as cumsum_sal
 from (select emp_id,name,salary,cumulative_salary,(row_number() over(order by emp_id)-1)/3 as grp
       from tbl
      ) t
)
update cte set cumulative_salary=cumsum_sal
```

Comment: The query works absolutely fine.How to implement the above logic in an update statement or through a cursor.

Comment: @user3484775 .. check out the edit to `update` the table..i assume `cumulative_salary` is the column to `update`.

Comment: Actually, i am using sql server 2008 which does not support the over() function. So I am trying to implement it using a cursor. At present using cursor I am able to update the cumulative salary but not per every 3 rows.